# MySQL Explain clarification

Tags: mysql, sql, database, explain, sql-execution-plan

My question is if I have the correct interpretation of the Explain command for the following query. And why isn't the last step of the query evaluation shown by the explain command?

Explain Output

[image]

Query :

```
SELECT COUNT(R.RID) FROM R, S WHERE R.RID=S.RID AND R.B=5 AND S.E=5;
```

MySQL Explanation :

1. Using the R table, scan through all records (TYPE = ALL) that satisfy R.B = 5.
2. Afterwards, using the records retrieved above (TYPE = REF), get all records that satisfy R.RID = S.RID.
3. Lastly, through the records retrieved from the second batch, it will search through the record to find which satisfy S.E = 5.

Comment: Steps 2 and 3 are actually merged in one cycle: the WHERE condition on S is evaluated during the reference loop. Also because all tuples are aggregate functions, so it makes sense keeping a running total in the reference loop to exploit data locality.

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense.  I don't understand why there is not an error.  What does `R` refer to?  Are you sure that is not a comma?

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes that should be a comma, I fixed it now.

Comment: @Sam . . . You should learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax.